# SQL Query pull column values from second table based on referencing from 2 tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

Sorry I tried searching for the answer and getting stuck

I am trying to inner join two tables to pull a value e.g.

```
table 1
--------
column a
column b
column c

table 2
--------
column a
column d
```

So, I want to pull all columns from `table 1` and then, where `column a` appears in `table 2`, I want to pull `column d`

Just not sure if inner join is right or how to write it

Answer (score 3):

There are four types of join:

```
JOIN: Return rows when there is at least one match in both tables
LEFT JOIN: Return all rows from the left table, even if there are no matches in the right table
RIGHT JOIN: Return all rows from the right table, even if there are no matches in the left table
FULL JOIN: Return rows when there is a match in one of the tables
```

as listed on http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

You want a LEFT JOIN from your description

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.d FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.a = table2.a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select table1.*, table2.d from table1 left join table2 on table1.a = table2.a
```